# Does Youtube alter audio in any particular way?

Tags: audio, youtube

My question is regarding the quality of audio in youtube.I usually listen to songs in youtube(@ 360p) and it is awesome. But when i download the same song(@ 360p) and listen to it; it feels kind of dull. I am using a latest VLC media player in my system and i want to know what settings i have to change in VLC to get the same quality as youtube or i have to download any other players. There is a similar question i found in [yahoo answers](http://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120110125520AAAP5OK) but the answer is not proper. I have downloaded youtube videos using IDM download manager.

Comment: The problem is that the file you downloaded is likely not the same video you watched on the site.  YouTube supports many codecs and many transport methods.  Your download tool probably picked something different than what your browser used.

Comment: @Brad - why not make that an answer, that sounds like a more likely possibility than my answer.  I'm actually going to delete mine because I'm pretty sure yours is the correct one.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the file you downloaded is likely not the same video you watched on the site.

YouTube supports many codecs and transport methods. Your download tool probably picked something different than what your browser used.  In some cases, YouTube also supports adjusting the bitrate of what you are watching progressively.  If you use a download tool, it will generally force the bitrate to be fixed.